# How do I find the value of the summation: $\dfrac{1}{1^2}+\dfrac{1}{7^2}+\dfrac{1}{9^2}+\dfrac{1}{15^2}+\dfrac{1}{17^2}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I used a flawed approach to generalizing Basel-like problems, Please refer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4769685

I assumed $\cos=0$ (for which the roots are $\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{-\pi}{2},\dfrac{3\pi}{2},\cdots$ $a_0$ becomes 1) for deriving the Basel problem in the cited answer, if instead I used $\cos=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ (for which the roots are $\dfrac{\pi}{4},\dfrac{9\pi}{4},\dfrac{-7\pi}{4},\cdots$ $a_0$ becomes $1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$) the resulting summation would be:

$\dfrac{1}{1^2}+\dfrac{1}{7^2}+\dfrac{1}{9^2}+\dfrac{1}{15^2}+\dfrac{1}{17^2}+\cdots$

Which results in the value $$\dfrac{\pi^2\cdot(\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}+1))}{32}=\dfrac{1}{1^2}+\dfrac{1}{7^2}+\dfrac{1}{9^2}+\dfrac{1}{15^2}+\dfrac{1}{17^2}+\cdots$$

These results can be seemingly generalized as (Where $X_e=\dfrac{\pi}{n}$):
$$\dfrac{X_e^2}{2}(\csc^2(X_e)(1+\cos(X_e)))=\dfrac{\pi^2}{2\cdot n^2}(\csc^2(\dfrac{\pi}{n})(1+\cos(\dfrac{\pi}{n})))=\dfrac{1}{1^2}+\dfrac{1}{(2n-1)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(1-4n)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(1+4n)^2}+\cdots$$ (For n>1)

However I acknowledge that the method I used is fundamentally flawed. Is there an alternate derivation for finding the value of the summation and by extension the observed generalization? If yes, has this generalization been found before or is it wrong?

Comment: Another interesting summation when $n=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$, $$\dfrac{\pi^2}{72}(2(2+\sqrt{3}))=\dfrac{1}{1^2}+\dfrac{1}{11^2}+\dfrac{1}{13^2}+\dfrac{1}{23^2}+\dfrac{1}{25^2}+\cdots$$

Comment: What is the general term of the summation? I can’t recognise any patterns within the terms.

Comment: The denominators follow a pattern, +10,+2,+10,+2... For the summation in the question, +6,+2,+6,+2...

Comment: The initial formula is equivalent to $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\left(2^3 k+1\right)^2}+\frac{1}{\left(2^3 k-1\right)^2}\right)+1=\frac{1}{32} \left(\sqrt{2}+2\right) \pi^2\tag{1},$$ but I don't understand the generalization since $$\frac{X_e^2}{2} \csc\left(X_e\right) \left(1+\cos\left(X_e\right)\right) \ne \frac{\pi^2}{2 n^2}  \csc^2\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right) \left(1+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right)\tag{2}$$ for $X_e=\frac{\pi}{n}$. Why are you squaring the $\csc$ term on the right side of formula (2) above?

Comment: A typo,  thank you for pointing it out. How did you evaluate the summation?? Is there another way?

Comment: I initially evaluated the summation with Mathematica, but [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1+%2B+Sum%5B%281%2F%282%5E3+k+-+1%29%5E2+%2B+1%2F%282%5E3+k+%2B+1%29%5E2%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+1%2C+Infinity%7D%5D) gives the same result.

Comment: Noting that $$1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{\left(2^2 3 k+1\right)^2}+\frac{1}{\left(2^2 3 k-1\right)^2}\right)=\frac{1}{36} \left(\sqrt{3}+2\right) \pi^2\tag{3},$$ are you asking about the generalization $$1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\left(2^2 n k+1\right)^2}+\frac{1}{\left(2^2 n k-1\right)^2}\right)=\frac{\pi^2 \csc^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4 n}\right)}{16 n^2}\tag{4}?$$

Comment: Yesss where did you find this generalization? I want to read about it and figure out if what I've observed is a subset of the generalization or something

Comment: Mathematica and [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1+%2B+Sum%5B%281%2F%282%5E2+n+k+-+1%29%5E2+%2B+1%2F%282%5E2+n+k+%2B+1%29%5E2%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+1%2C+%5C%5BInfinity%5D%7D%5D) both give this generalization, but it's a conditional result and you can see the conditions for $n$ on WolframAlpha.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I couldn't find any other references to this generalization on the internet. Still unclear about how it was derived though...

Comment: I believe the generalization follows from the formula $$\csc^2(z)=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty }^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z-\pi k)^2},\quad \frac{z}{\pi}\notin\mathbb{Z}\tag{5}$$ which can be found [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Csc/06/05/0005/) on the Wolfram function site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's denote $\displaystyle S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{(kn+1)^2}+\frac1{(kn-1)^2}\right)=\frac1{2n^2}\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac1{(k+1/n)^2}+\frac1{(k-1/n)^2}\right)-1$

To evaluate $\displaystyle S_0=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac1{(k+1/n)^2}+\frac1{(k-1/n)^2}\right)$ we integrate along a big circle (of the radius $R$) in the complex plane.

Leading $R\to\infty$
$$\oint_{C}\pi\cot(\pi z)\left(\frac1{(z+1/n)^2}+\frac1{(z-1/n)^2}\right)dz=0=2\pi i\sum \operatorname{Res}$$
$$\Rightarrow\,\,S_0+\underset{z=\frac1n}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{(z-\frac1n)^2}+\underset{z=-\frac1n}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{(z+\frac1n)^2}=0$$
$$\Rightarrow\,\,S_0=\frac{2\pi^2}{\sin^2\frac\pi n}$$
and
$$\boxed{\,\,S+1=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{(kn+1)^2}+\frac1{(kn-1)^2}\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{n^2}\frac1{\sin^2\frac\pi n}\,\,}$$
Taking $n=8$
$$1+\dfrac{1}{7^2}+\dfrac{1}{9^2}+\dfrac{1}{15^2}+\dfrac{1}{17^2}+\cdots=\frac{\pi^2}{64}\frac1{\sin^2\frac\pi8}=\frac{\pi^2}{16}\frac{\cos^2\frac\pi8}{\sin^2\frac\pi4}=\frac{\pi^2}{16}\big(1+\cos\frac\pi4\big)$$
etc.

Comment: I didn't understand why you did the integration part but thank you regardless :). I will learn the concepts behind this.